# How to solve issue with "Bulk Delete" module?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I installed "Bulk Delete" module for Drupal 7.x, and tried to bulk delete all Feed items (1575 items), but when I click Delete button, it just show page with message "Deleting 1575 nodes in 80 operations", without errors or warnings. So page just stay with this message, but not delete anything. Feed items remain in place, that's all. What is wrong?

[bulkdelete-7.x-1.2.tar.gz](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/bulkdelete-7.x-1.2.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with other content types. I just hit phpmyadmin and find the table and delete the data there when something funny like that happens.

Clear your cache to be sure though.

Comment: I have read that deleting directly from MySQL isn't a good way, as this delete not all related data, may cause issues.